# Varnish - how to check JWT signature using digest Vmod?

Tags: jwt, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have a DockerFile based on Varnish 7.0 alpine, I have a custom vcl file to handle JWT authentication. We pass the JWT as a Bearer in the header.

I am based on this example: https://feryn.eu/blog/validating-json-web-tokens-in-varnish/

```
    set req.http.tmpPayload = regsub(req.http.x-token,"[^\.]+\.([^\.]+)\.[^\.]+$","\1");
    set req.http.tmpHeader = regsub(req.http.x-token,"([^\.]+)\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+","\1");
    set req.http.tmpRequestSig = regsub(req.http.x-token,"^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+\.([^\.]+)$","\1");

    set req.http.tmpCorrectSig = digest.base64url_nopad_hex(digest.hmac_sha256(std.fileread("/jwt/privateKey.pem"), req.http.tmpHeader + "." + req.http.tmpPayload));

    std.log("req sign " + req.http.tmpRequestSig);
    std.log("calc sign " + req.http.tmpCorrectSig);

    if(req.http.tmpRequestSig != req.http.tmpCorrectSig) {
        std.log("invalid signature match");
        return(synth(403, "Invalid JWT signature"));
    }
```

My problem is that `tmpCorrectSig` is empty, I don't know if I can load from a file, since my file contains new lines and other caracteres ?

For information, this Vmod is doing what I want: https://code.uplex.de/uplex-varnish/libvmod-crypto, but I can't install it on my Arm M1 pro architecture, I spent so much time trying...

Can I achieve what I want?

Comment: I saw your comment on my Youtube video and I'll provide the necessary information on how to validate HS256 & RS256 JWTs. It might take me a day or 2, stay tuned.

Comment: @ThijsFeryn Would be amazing, I try everything to install the libmod-crypto on the alpine version, but impossible, the libmod-digest works. But I don't think you can do it with RS256 algo? we don't use H256 but RS256 for the JWT

Comment: @VincentDecaux should one of the answers flagged as correct?

Comment: @NilsGoroll no, still doesn't work for me on M1 architecture. For now, I just a different Dockerfile to disable Varnish for M1 users for local development.

Comment: in https://gitlab.com/uplex/varnish/libvmod-crypto/-/issues/3 you said it worked. So if it does not, let's reopen the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have a valid solution that leverages the `libvmod-crypto`. The VCL supports both `HS256` and `RS256`.

These are the commands I used to generated the certificates:

```sh
cd /etc/varnish
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m PEM -f jwtRS256.key
openssl rsa -in jwtRS256.key -pubout -outform PEM -out jwtRS256.key.pub
```

I use https://jwt.io/ to generate a token and paste in the values from my certificates to encrypt the signature.

#### The VCL code

This is the VCL code that will extract the JWT from the `token` cookie:

```
vcl 4.1;

import blob;
import digest;
import crypto;
import std;

sub vcl_init {
    new v = crypto.verifier(sha256,std.fileread("/etc/varnish/jwtRS256.key.pub"));
}

sub vcl_recv {
    call jwt;
}

sub jwt {
    if(req.http.cookie ~ "^([^;]+;[ ]*)*token=[^\.]+\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+([ ]*;[^;]+)*$") {
        set req.http.x-token = ";" + req.http.Cookie;
        set req.http.x-token = regsuball(req.http.x-token, "; +", ";");
        set req.http.x-token = regsuball(req.http.x-token, ";(token)=","; \1=");
        set req.http.x-token = regsuball(req.http.x-token, ";[^ ][^;]*", "");
        set req.http.x-token = regsuball(req.http.x-token, "^[; ]+|[; ]+$", "");

        set req.http.tmpHeader = regsub(req.http.x-token,"token=([^\.]+)\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+","\1");
        set req.http.tmpTyp = regsub(digest.base64url_decode(req.http.tmpHeader),{"^.*?"typ"\s*:\s*"(\w+)".*?$"},"\1");
        set req.http.tmpAlg = regsub(digest.base64url_decode(req.http.tmpHeader),{"^.*?"alg"\s*:\s*"(\w+)".*?$"},"\1");

        if(req.http.tmpTyp != "JWT") {
            return(synth(400, "Token is not a JWT: " + req.http.tmpHeader));
        }
        if(req.http.tmpAlg != "HS256" && req.http.tmpAlg != "RS256") {
            return(synth(400, "Token does not use a HS256 or RS256 algorithm"));
        }

        set req.http.tmpPayload = regsub(req.http.x-token,"token=[^\.]+\.([^\.]+)\.[^\.]+$","\1");
        set req.http.tmpRequestSig = regsub(req.http.x-token,"^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+\.([^\.]+)$","\1");

        if(req.http.tempAlg == "HS256") {
            set req.http.tmpCorrectSig = digest.base64url_nopad_hex(digest.hmac_sha256("SlowWebSitesSuck",req.http.tmpHeader + "." + req.http.tmpPayload));        
            if(req.http.tmpRequestSig != req.http.tmpCorrectSig) {
                return(synth(403, "Invalid HS256 JWT signature"));
            }           
        } else {
            if (! v.update(req.http.tmpHeader + "." + req.http.tmpPayload)) {
                return (synth(500, "vmod_crypto error"));
            }

            if (! v.valid(blob.decode(decoding=BASE64URLNOPAD, encoded=req.http.tmpRequestSig))) {
                return(synth(403, "Invalid RS256 JWT signature"));
            }
        }

        set req.http.tmpPayload = digest.base64url_decode(req.http.tmpPayload);
        set req.http.X-Login = regsub(req.http.tmpPayload,{"^.*?"login"\s*:\s*(\w+).*?$"},"\1");
        set req.http.X-Username = regsub(req.http.tmpPayload,{"^.*?"sub"\s*:\s*"(\w+)".*?$"},"\1");

        unset req.http.tmpHeader;
        unset req.http.tmpTyp;
        unset req.http.tmpAlg;
        unset req.http.tmpPayload;
        unset req.http.tmpRequestSig;
        unset req.http.tmpCorrectSig;
        unset req.http.tmpPayload;
    }
}
```

#### Installing libvmod-crypto

`libvmod-crypto` is required to use `RS256`, which is not supported by `libvmod-digest`.

Unfortunately I'm getting an error when running the `./configure` script:

```
./configure: line 12829: syntax error: unexpected newline (expecting ")")
```

I'll talk to the maintainer of the VMOD and see if we can figure out someway to fix this. If this is an urgent matter, I suggest you use a non-Alpine Docker container for the time being.

Comment: Looking, thanks for your time, I have the same error on the libvmod-crypto... I talked to the maintainer of the Vmod already (see gitlab issues), I tried with a non alpine (6.6), see here: https://github.com/opositatest/varnish-jwt/issues/13

Comment: Thread of the configure error: https://gitlab.com/uplex/varnish/libvmod-crypto/-/issues/3

Comment: By the way, missreaded your answer, but using libvmod-crypto, it works (see https://github.com/opositatest/varnish-jwt/blob/main/varnish/default.vcl, we copied this code), just I can't update the crypto vmod to varnish 6.6 or 7

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the configure error was caused by a missing `-dev` package, see [the gitlab issue](https://gitlab.com/uplex/varnish/libvmod-crypto/-/issues/3) (the reference is in a comment, but I think it should be more prominent).

The main issue in the original question is that `digest.hmac_sha256()` can not be used to verify `RS256` signatures. A JWT `RS256` signature is a SHA256 hash of the subject encrypted with an RSA private key, which can then be verified by decrypting with the RSA public key and checking the signature. This is what `crypto.verifier(sha256, ...)` does.

In this regard, [Thijs' previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70621876/2051429) is already correct.

Yet the code which is circulating and has been referenced here it nothing I would endorse. Among other issues, a fundamental problem is that regular expressions are used to (pretend to) parse JSON, which is simply not correct.

I use a better implementation for long, but just did not get around to publishing it. So now is the time, I guess.

I have just [added VCL snippets from production code for JWT parsing and validation](https://code.uplex.de/uplex-varnish/libvmod-frozen/tree/master/examples/jwt).

The example is used like so with the `jwt` directory in `vcl_path`:

```
include "jwt/jwt.vcl";
include "jwt/rsa_keys.vcl";

sub vcl_recv {
    jwt.set(YOUR_JWT);  # replace YOUR_JWT with an actual variable/header/function

    call recv_jwt_validate;

    # do things with jwt_payload.extract(".scope")
}
```

Here, the `scope` claim contains the data that we are actually interested in for further processing, if you want to use other claims, just rename `.scope` or add another `jwt_payload.expect(CLAIM, ...)` and then use `jwt_payload.extract(CLAIM)`.

This example uses some vmods, which we developed and maintain in particular with JWT in mind, though not exclusively:

- [crypto](https://code.uplex.de/uplex-varnish/libvmod-crypto) ([use gitlab mirror for issues](https://gitlab.com/uplex/varnish/libvmod-crypto)) for RS signatures (mostly RS256)
- [frozen](https://code.uplex.de/uplex-varnish/libvmod-frozen) ([use gitlab mirror for issues](https://code.uplex.de/uplex-varnish/libvmod-frozen)) for JSON parsing

Additionally, we use

- [re2](https://code.uplex.de/uplex-varnish/libvmod-re2) ([use gitlab mirror for issues](https://gitlab.com/uplex/varnish/libvmod-re2)) to efficiently split the JWT into the three parts (header, payload, signature)
- and `taskvar` from [objvar](https://code.uplex.de/uplex-varnish/varnish-objvar) ([gitlab](https://gitlab.com/uplex/varnish/varnish-objvar)) for proper variables.

One could do without these two vmods (re2 could be replaced by the re vmod or even regsub and taskvar with headers), but they make the code more efficient and cleaner.

[blobdigest](https://code.uplex.de/uplex-varnish/libvmod-blobdigest) ([gitlab](https://gitlab.com/uplex/varnish/libvmod-blobdigest)) is not contained in the example, but can be used to validate HS signtures (e.g. HS256).

Comment: First, thanks really for sharing your jwt implementation, we saw the JWT Vmod on the varnish plus , but prices are ridiculous. Then, as I wrote on Gitlab issue, your lib works perfectly, just not on Alpine distri, or with 6.6 Varnish too. And I need to up the version for the Arm architecture. Will take a big look to your code, thanks again